# Break sentence into parts from full stop, comma, and & but

Tags: python

`sentence = "Very disorganized and hard professor. Does not come to classes on time, she grades tough, does not help on anything. She says come for help but when you go to her office hour, she is not there to help."`

I want to break this sentence into parts from full stop, comma, and & but.
the output should be like,

```
Very disorganized 
and hard professor. 
Does not come to classes on time, 
she grades tough, 
does not help on anything. 
She says come for help 
but when you go to her office hour, 
she is not there to help.
```

for now I am using,

```
sample = re.split(r' *[\.\?!][\'"\)\]]* *', sentence)

print (sample)
```

and this only break the sentence from full stops.
output,

```
['Very disorganized and hard professor', 'Does not come to classes on time, she grades tough, does not help on anything', 'She says come for help but when you go to her office hour, she is not there to help']
```

Any idea how to do this.

Comment: importing  [string.punctuation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation)  can be helpful here; it contains all punctuation marks. Re your regex, it is hard to read and you might want to consider using `\W` instead, which matches all non-word characters in one symbol. Regarding your present regex, the comma character is not in there...?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this one, but I guess that the `nltk` library might help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to add in newline characters where your stopwords are encountered.

The regex is simply: `(and|\.|but|,)`, which matches your stopwords.  Then you replace that group with itself, plus a newline character.

```
>>> import re   
>>> sentence = "Very disorganized and hard professor. Does not come to classes on time, she grades tough, does not help on anything. She says come for help but when you go to her office hour, she is not there to help."  
>>> sample = re.sub(r'(and|\.|but|,)', r'\1\n', sentence)
>>> sample
Very disorganized and
 hard professor.
 Does not come to classes on time,
 she grades tough,
 does not help on anything.
 She says come for help but
 when you go to her office hour,
 she is not there to help.
```

If you want it in a list:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(and|\.|but|,)', r'\1\n', sentence).split('\n')
['Very disorganized and', ' hard professor.', ' Does not come to classes on time,', ' she grades tough,', ' does not help on anything.', ' She says come for help but', ' when you go to her office hour,', ' she is not there to help.', '']
```

If you want to remove the whitespace before each following line, you can use this:

```
sample = re.sub(r'(and|\.|but|,)(?:\s)', r'\1\n', sentence)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I looked for. This worked fine :)

Comment: Happy to help, happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Result=re.split(r'[.,&]', sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a loop

```
for x in ['.', ',', 'and', 'but']:
   sentence=sentence.replace(x, x+'\n')
```

Adds a `\n` after each of those delimiters.

Output:

```
Very disorganized and
 hard professor.
 Does not come to classes on time,
 she grades tough,
 does not help on anything.
 She says come for help but
 when you go to her office hour,
 she is not there to help.
```